# Self hosted SignalR cross platform SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, macos, ssl, signalr, owin

I have created an application in C#/.Net4.5 that is self hosting SignalR on localhost and it works well on Windows and Mac OSX.
Now I need to add SSL/TLS to SignalR but cannot find examples on how to do this in a cross platform manner.
For windows there are several examples using netsh but none for Mac OS X (or Linux, but that's secondary).

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to set up SignalR to use an SSL certificate on Windows as well as on Mac OS X? (e.g. with a .Net or Mono class)
- If not, how can I do it on Mac OS X?
- And secondary, is it possible to do it without admin rights? (I can use any port, not just 80 or 423)

I already know how to create a self-signed certificate and a root CA and how to add them to a store.

As for what I'm using:

- SignalR 2.2.0
- Owin 3.0.1
- .Net 4.5

How I create SignalR now:

```
string urlSignalR = "http://localhost:63000";
var SignalRServer = WebApp.Start(urlSignalR, SignalRStartup);

private void SignalRStartup(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Comment: Mono has its `httpcfg` command to guide you configure certificates to ports.

Comment: @LexLi awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono has a command line utility named httpcfg,

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/en/man1/httpcfg.1.html